# Laurent series expansion of $()=\tan(/(-1))$ around $ = 1$

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series

I am tasked with finding whether the function $()=\tan(/(-1))$ can be developed into a Laurent series around $=1$, and if so what is the radius of convergence and what is the residue?

My initial attempt was at developing the expression into something like the following:

$
\tan(\frac{z}{z-1}) = 
\tan(1 + \frac{1}{z-1}) = 
\frac{\sin(1 + \frac{1}{z-1})}{\cos(1 + \frac{1}{z-1})} = 
\frac{
  \sin(1)\cos(\frac{1}{z-1}) -  \cos(1)\sin(\frac{1}{z-1})
}{
  \cos(1)\cos(\frac{z}{z-1}) - \sin(1)\sin(\frac{z}{z-1})
}
$

I know how to develop either the numerator or denominator into taylor series expansions based on this, but seems to me like would get quite hairy to explicitly try to develop the quotient (possible but I don't believe thats the purpose of the exercise).

A couple of other directions:

- try to show that $f(z)$ is indeed defined and analytic in each punctured disc of $z=1$ but that there are two sequences of complex numbers converging to 1 that have different limits and therefore it is an essential singularity (e.g. $\lim_{n->\infty}f(a_n) \ne \lim_{n->\infty}f(b_n)$). perhaps something like $a_n = 1 + \frac{1}{2n\pi - 1}$ and $b_n = 1 + \frac{1}{2(n+1)\pi - 1}$
- try to show that at $z = 1$ we do not actually have an isolated singularity since we can find a point at any neighborhood of $z=1$ in which $f(z)$ is not defined? for example at $a_n = 1 + \frac{1}{(2n+1)\frac{\pi}{2} - 1}$ for every n the numerator is zero and therefore it is undefined, and $\lim_{n->\infty}a_n = 1$ I believe?

Comment: What do you know about Laurent series?

Comment: In my course context they can be developed around a point if it is an isolated singularity of the function which in this case seems right? If so I am then supposed to manipulate the expressions via various Taylor series expansions to arrive at explicit formula that shows type of singularity (eg simple pole essential singularity etc) and radius of convergence

Comment: If you will not like to be downvoted, you'd better show your attempts. Did you try expanding $\tan x$ and its argument $z/(z-1)=1-1/(1-z)$ geometric series...

Comment: Sure, will add some of my (futile) attempts so far..

Comment: @MathArt I've added a few of my attempts - my best attempt I believe is showing this is not an isolated singularity at all using a series of numbers as I write in my updated question body. Is that right?